# Process `polkitd` using a lot of CPU (too much?)

Tags: linux, centos, cpu

I'm running a fresh new install of CentOS 7 x64 w/ Cinnamon as my window manager. Occasionally I'm getting some major lag doing basic tasks, so I opened up an instance of `top` and it appears that the process `polkitd` (under user `polkitd`) is using a good bit of CPU.

It fluctuates from consistently 10% CPU to even as high as 70%, and I can't figure out what the process is all about, if it's necessary, and if not how can I stop it?

Thanks in advance for any advice you all may have!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what was going on.

I had the applet 'Multi-core System Monitor' installed and added to one of my taskbars. It appears there's a bug in that code which causes polkitd to have a ton of CPU usage that steadily increases over time to unreasonable levels.

More info on [applet causes continuously increasing memory usage](https://github.com/ccadeptic23/Multi-Core-System-Monitor/issues/12)

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit research and posted here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1600161#c3

A workaround that I've been using is to remove /etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Account.desktop until the above mentioned bug is fixed. The only function you will lose is the notification of expiring account password.